# On click of a button a textfield has to be displayed?

Tags: objective-c, button, uitextfield

I have a button and a textfield. Button is just below the textField. Now when I click on the button a new textfield should be displayed below the first text field and the frame of the button should also be changed. When I have tried this it worked for the first time but when I click a second time the new textfield is not displaying and the button frame is also not changing. Help me with this issue.

The code that i have written is:

```
-(void)onboardCertificatesAddBtnBtnTap
{
    int x, y;

    if (y =585, x=632) {

        _boardCertificationField= [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, y+50, self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2-25, 40)];
        _boardCertificationField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
        _boardCertificationField.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        [_scrollView addSubview:_boardCertificationField];

        _expDateField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, y+50, self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2-40, 40)];
        _expDateField .font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
        _expDateField .borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        [_scrollView addSubview:_expDateField];

        _boardCertificatesAddBtn.frame = CGRectMake(5, x+50, 20, 20);

        [_boardCertificatesAddBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_scrollView addSubview:_boardCertificatesAddBtn];

        [_boardCertificatesAddBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onboardCertificatesAddBtnBtnTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        y=y+50;
        x=x+50;
    }        
   else  {

        _boardCertificationField= [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, y+50, self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2-25, 40)];
        _boardCertificationField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
        _boardCertificationField.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        [_scrollView addSubview:_boardCertificationField];

        _expDateField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, y+50, self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2-40, 40)];
        _expDateField .font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
        _expDateField .borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        [_scrollView addSubview:_expDateField];

        _boardCertificatesAddBtn.frame = CGRectMake(5, x+50, 20, 20);

        [_boardCertificatesAddBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_scrollView addSubview:_boardCertificatesAddBtn];

        [_boardCertificatesAddBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onboardCertificatesAddBtnBtnTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        y=y+50;
        x=x+50;
    } 
}
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: i have edited my question please check the code in it

Comment: what you are doing in if else, as code are same in both and declare x and y globally. Issue is with X and Y as these are initialized every time when you click on button

Comment: Then how i have to write the code? Can you explain kindly

Answer (score 0):

Declare x and in @implementation ViewController block
like

```
    @implementation Viewcontroller
 {
 int x,y;
 }
```

and write other code as

```
 -(void)onboardCertificatesAddBtnBtnTap
 {


if (y =585, x=632) {

    _boardCertificationField= [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, y+50, self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2-25, 40)];
    _boardCertificationField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    _boardCertificationField.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [_scrollView addSubview:_boardCertificationField];

    _expDateField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, y+50, self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2-40, 40)];
    _expDateField .font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    _expDateField .borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [_scrollView addSubview:_expDateField];

    _boardCertificatesAddBtn.frame = CGRectMake(5, x+50, 20, 20);

    [_boardCertificatesAddBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_scrollView addSubview:_boardCertificatesAddBtn];

    [_boardCertificatesAddBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onboardCertificatesAddBtnBtnTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    y=y+50;
    x=x+50;
}        
      else  {

    _boardCertificationField= [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, y+50, self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2-25, 40)];
    _boardCertificationField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    _boardCertificationField.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [_scrollView addSubview:_boardCertificationField];

    _expDateField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, y+50, self.scrollView.frame.size.width/2-40, 40)];
    _expDateField .font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    _expDateField .borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [_scrollView addSubview:_expDateField];

    _boardCertificatesAddBtn.frame = CGRectMake(5, x+50, 20, 20);

    [_boardCertificatesAddBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_scrollView addSubview:_boardCertificatesAddBtn];

    [_boardCertificatesAddBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onboardCertificatesAddBtnBtnTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    y=y+50;
    x=x+50;
}
```